# Basic beautiful soup help - Glastonbury lineup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to python. What I would like to do is extract all the bands announced from glastonbury festival this year using python and beautiful soup. I want to dump all bands to a text file and eventually create a spotify playlist based on the top track for each artist.

The list of artists I want to extract from [www.efestivals.co.uk/festivals/glastonbury/2013/lineup.shtml#](http://www.efestivals.co.uk/festivals/glastonbury/2013/lineup.shtml#) (I actually want to be on the A-Z tab rather than the Friday tab)

I have tried to print the bands to the terminal first but I am getting blank results. Here is what I've tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

#efestivals page with all glastonbury acts
url = "http://www.efestivals.co.uk/festivals/glastonbury/2013/lineup.shtml#"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

bands = soup.findAll('a')
for eachband in bands:
   print eachband.string
```

Basically, I need help to get onto the A-Z tab and also extract each band. I also want only the confirmed bands (Those with `img src="/img2009/lineup_confirmed.gif"`). I am not very familiar with html but this seems like a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract links for the confirmed bands from A-Z table:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

try:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
except ImportError: # Python 3
    from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

def table_after_atoz(tag):
    '''Whether tag is a <table> after an element with id="LUA to Z".'''
    if tag.name == 'table' and 'TableLineupBox' in tag.get('class', ''):
        for tag in tag.previous_elements: # go back
            if not isinstance(tag, NavigableString): # skip strings
                return tag.get('id') == "LUA to Z"

def confirmed_band_links(soup):
    table = soup.find(table_after_atoz) # find A to Z table
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'): # find all rows (including nested tables)
        if tr.find('img', alt="confirmed"): # row with a confirmed band?
            yield tr.find('a', href=re.compile(r'^/festivals/bands')) # a link

def main():
    url = "http://www.efestivals.co.uk/festivals/glastonbury/2013/lineup.shtml"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
    for link in confirmed_band_links(soup):
        print("%s\t%s" % (link['href'], link.string))

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to go about this. This is just one example that seems to work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 as ul

url = "http://www.efestivals.co.uk/festivals/glastonbury/2013/lineup.shtml#"
page = ul.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

elements = soup.findAll('img', {'src': '/img2009/lineup_confirmed.gif'})

bands = [e.next_element.next_element.text for e in elements]

print bands[1:11]
```

Output:

```
[u'Arctic Monkeys', u'Dizzee Rascal', u'The Vaccines', u'Kenny Rogers']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

#efestivals page with all glasto acts
url = "http://www.efestivals.co.uk/festivals/glastonbury/2013/lineup.shtml#"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

bands = soup.findAll('a', href=True)
for band in bands:
    if band['href'].startswith("/festivals/bands"):
        print band.string
```